# What does Route::model mean in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-routing

Can any one explain these lines ? How it works?

```
public function boot()
{
     parent::boot();

     Route::model('user', App\User::class);
}
```

Next, define a route that contains a `{user}` parameter:

```
$router->get('profile/{user}', function(App\User $user) {
  //
});
```

Comment: Unclear, please edit and give some details, context, and what you want to achive.

Comment: Please read the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called [Route Model Explicit Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#explicit-binding)

With this:

```
Route::model('user', App\User::class);
```

you're saying: when a `'user'` string is used in a route as a parameter, create a model of `App\User::class` for me, that has the same id as the parameter passed to the route. Then inject the model on the route method handler.

For example, the url: `'profile/10'` will match this route:

```
$router->get('profile/{user}', function(App\User $user) {
  //
});
```

And the `App\User` model with an id of 10 will be automatically fetched by Laravel

From a general point of view, normally in your routes you do something like this:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    //fetch the user from db...
    $user = User::find($id);

    //do something with the $user...
}
```

with Route Model Binding you can do:

```
public function edit(App\User $user)
{
    //do something with $user...
}
```

avoiding to fetch the model from the database: Laravel will do it for you